# Why can't PHEVs be charged by the engine?

Tags: electric-vehicle, plug-in-hybrid

I was reading a little bit about PHEVs [here](https://www.carbuyer.co.uk/tips-and-advice/303135/hybrid-vs-plug-in-hybrid-vs-electric-cars). There's also Rory's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsQORFOUgTY) about why PHEVs are pointless.

The article says "The battery’s size means it can’t be recharged by the car as it drives along like a regular hybrid. Instead, just like a fully electric car, you have to plug in a PHEV in order to recharge the battery."

Why is this the case? What does the size of the battery have to do with the ability of a petrol/diesel engine to charge it? And are there engineering solutions in the near future that will allow us to have PHEVs that can be charged either by plugging in or by the petrol/diesel motor?

Answer (score 1):

While searching using the terms "how do plug-in hybrids charge?" I discovered a number of inaccurate sources. As you suggest, the size of the battery has nothing to do with the ability of an ICE to charge it. The size of the battery would affect the rate of charge. PHEVs are engineered to use an engine mounted generator to charge the pack if the level is depleted beyond a certain amount.

A good example is the [Chevrolet Volt](https://www.treehugger.com/how-do-hybrid-batteries-recharge-85469):

> Plug-in hybrids, like the Chevrolet Volt, operate in much the same way
> as a hybrid by providing an all-electric driving range using a battery
> pack. Once the battery has been depleted, the vehicle can slip back
> to being a regular fuel-fed hybrid and recharge its batteries using
> the gasoline-powered motor as a generator.